# GenericJMXConfMBean: No MBean matched the ObjectName kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec,request=Produce

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, collectd

I am working on a project where I am trying to collect the apache Kakfa request rate metric using the mbean metric **'kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec,request={Produce|FetchConsumer|FetchFollower}'** defined in the apache documentation. I am using collectd  plugin to collect these metrics. But I am getting the error No MBean matched with the object name. For other mbean metrics, it is working correctly.

I tried pulling the metrics using jmx tool as well and it failed for this metric.
**kafka-run-class kafka.tools.JmxTool --jmx-url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9090/jmxrmi --object-name kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec,request=Produce**

I want the request rate metric for all the 3 producer, fetch consumer, fetch follower.
Should I be using some other metric ? The kafka version I am using is 2.1

Answer (score 0):

The metric has been added with an API version tag. See the description below:

> KIP-272 added API version tag to the metric kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec,request={Produce|FetchConsumer|FetchFollower|...}. This metric now becomes kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec,request={Produce|FetchConsumer|FetchFollower|...},version={0|1|2|3|...}. This will impact JMX monitoring tools that do not automatically aggregate. To get the total count for a specific request type, the tool needs to be updated to aggregate across different versions.

Retry with the version tag to see if it works.